# How to change child text size when clicking parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap

I want to click on a header then the size of the text below the header changes.

I can do this by using a id but this changes all the text on the page which the id is added to. I just want the text next to it/ group of it to change.

This is the code which I am using:

```
<h1 value="Increase Font Size" onclick="increaseFontSize('increasetext', 10)" class=" page-heading title"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i>Main Text </h1>

<p> the text which needs to increase<p/>

<h1 value="Increase Font Size" onclick="increaseFontSize('increasetext', 10)" class=" page-heading title"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i>Main Text </h1>

<p> the text which needs to increase<p/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function increaseFontSize(id, increaseFactor){
 txt = document.getElementById(id);
 style = window.getComputedStyle(txt, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
 currentSize = parseFloat(style);
 txt.style.fontSize = (currentSize + increaseFactor) + 'px';
}
```

I could try different id on each text and header but that may cause other issues.

Comment: Are you using angularjs?

Comment: You actually should try with a diffrent id on each text, in HTML, an id must be unique. You'll most probably run into troubles later if you keep it like this. If you want the same value across the page, use `class` and `getElementsByClassName`. A wrapper element would be an easy way to solve your issue though.

Comment: Thank you could you expand on what you mean by wrapper element

Comment: If all the texts related to the `h1` that increase their size, and the `h1` itself are inside a parent element (wrapper), it is easier to restrict the selection, if it's already the case, and you can edit the question to add more of your HTML structure to the question, it can help

Comment: updated the code is this what you require

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to create a wrapper, here with a specific class, to contain all the elements you want to increase size. It's a bit trickier here with id because an HTML element does not have the `getElementById` function.

```html
<div class="increaseWrapper">
  <h1 value="Increase Font Size" onclick="increaseFontSize(this, 'increasetext', 10)" class=" page-heading title"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i>Main Text </h1>
  
  <p id="increasetext"> the text which needs to increase<p/>
</div>

<div class="increaseWrapper">
  <h1 value="Increase Font Size" onclick="increaseFontSize(this, 'increasetext', 10)" class=" page-heading title"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i>Main Text </h1>
  <div>
    <p id="increasetext"> the text which needs to increase<p/>
    <p id="increasetext"> the text which needs to increase<p/>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function increaseFontSize(element, id, increaseFactor){
  var parent = element;
  //traversing structure to find the wrapper (you can easily find shims of classList if you need to support older browsers)
  while(parent && !parent.classList.contains('increaseWrapper')){
    parent = parent.parentElement;
  }
  //if wrapper found, finding elements in wrapper and increase
  if(parent){
    var txt, elms = parent.getElementsByTagName("*"), i, l = elms.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      if (elms[i].id === id) {
        txt = elms[i];
        style = window.getComputedStyle(txt, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
        currentSize = parseFloat(style);
        txt.style.fontSize = (currentSize + increaseFactor) + 'px';
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

However, as I told you, it's much more semantically correct to use classes here, as an id must be unique, and easier because all HTML elements have the `getElementsByClassName` function:

```html
<div class="increaseWrapper">
  <h1 value="Increase Font Size" onclick="increaseFontSize(this, 'increasetext', 10)" class=" page-heading title"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i>Main Text </h1>
  
  <p class="increasetext"> the text which needs to increase<p/>
</div>

<div class="increaseWrapper">
  <h1 value="Increase Font Size" onclick="increaseFontSize(this, 'increasetext', 10)" class=" page-heading title"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i>Main Text </h1>
  <div>
    <p class="increasetext"> the text which needs to increase<p/>
    <p class="increasetext"> the text which needs to increase<p/>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function increaseFontSize(element, className, increaseFactor){
  var parent = element;
  //traversing structure to find the wrapper (you can easily find shims of classList if you need to support older browsers)
  while(parent && !parent.classList.contains('increaseWrapper')){
    parent = parent.parentElement;
  }
  //if wrapper found, finding elements in wrapper and increase
  if(parent){
    var txts = parent.getElementsByClassName(className), i, l = txts.length;
    for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
      style = window.getComputedStyle(txts[i], null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
      currentSize = parseFloat(style);
      txts[i].style.fontSize = (currentSize + increaseFactor) + 'px';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**NOTE**: With this code, the `h1` could as well increase its own size, as long as it has the wrapper class and there is an inner element with the increase class/id inside:

```
<h1 value="Increase Font Size" onclick="increaseFontSize(this, 'increasetext', 10)" class=" page-heading title increaseWrapper"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i><p class="increasetext">Main Text</p></h1>
```